# making a plsql comparison

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I am relativity new to sql and need some help.

I have a table called TREATMENT which has 2 fields:

- T_ID(primary key)
- T_NAME.

Some of these treatments should not be used with others. For example.. if T_ID = 'T001' is used with T_ID = 'T002' it will cause severe headaches. and I want to do this for a few of them.

So I need the PL/SQL to take a value from the user and which a T_ID and the program will output the colliding treatment.

thanks in advance

this is my table:

```
DROP TABLE TREATMENT CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
CREATE TABLE TREATMENT(
T_ID VARCHAR2(5) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
T_NAME VARCHAR2(15));

INSERT INTO TREATMENT VALUES
('T001','ACCUPUNCTURE');

INSERT INTO TREATMENT VALUES
('T002','MASSAGE');

INSERT INTO TREATMENT VALUES
('T003','SKIN CARE');

INSERT INTO TREATMENT VALUES
('T004','OSTEOPATHY');

INSERT INTO TREATMENT VALUES
('T005','HOMOEOPATHY');

INSERT INTO TREATMENT VALUES
('T006','PHYSIOTHERAPY');

INSERT INTO TREATMENT VALUES
('T007','PSYCHOLOGY');

INSERT INTO TREATMENT VALUES
('T008','DEMATOLOGY');

INSERT INTO TREATMENT VALUES
('T009','YOGA');

commit;
```

I want for example to restrict "yoga" and "dermatology" from being taken together as they will have side effects like. user inputs T009 and system replies... yoga should not be taken with dermatology. will cause headache

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired output.  I am removing hte MySQL tag.

Comment: sounds like you need rules or constraints on your table columns

Comment: makes sense @OurManInBananas but i dont know how i would make it output a message using just constraints and rule which is why i was trying to make a plspql to do that

Comment: What you show is a list table with the possible values. The logic you demand should be associated with the table, where you use these list values in combination with eg. a customer no and a date of agreement. On that table you can put a trigger that examines every new insert, if it contains illegal combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a data modelling problem.  You need another table to hold banned combinations.  Eg.

```
create table contraindication
   ( treatment1 VARCHAR2(5) 
     , treatment2 VARCHAR2(5)
     , primary key ci_pk (treatment1, treatment2) );

insert into contraindication values ('T008', 'T009');
```

Your procedure should look up this table.

You may find it helpful to insert both permutations, as this will make the query simpler (and more efficient if the list gets big):

```
insert into contraindication values ('T009', 'T008');
```